# After header tag, h1 is occurring as hyperlink, Whereas i have not defined any of the href tag. What could be the reason

Tags: html

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="homeblack" href="https://www.facebook.com/abhishek.ruined">ABOUT</li>
            <a class="homeblack" href="/#">PORTFOLIO
            <li>
                <li><a class="homeblack" href="/#">CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="loginbox"> 
         <img src="login.png" class="avatar"><br><br><br>
         ****<h1>Login Here</h1><br>****
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you please put your code inside a codepen.io so that we can pinpoint the exact problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't explicitly close any of the anchors in the list so the browser guesses at what you intended. Fix your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code in this codepen.io! https://codepen.io/ekk0/pen/BOZZxL This should fix it! Next time be careful to close your `<a>` tags!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, your problem is with closing tags correctly. Here's a fixed up version:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="homeblack" href="https://www.facebook.com/abhishek.ruined">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a class="homeblack" href="/#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a class="homeblack" href="/#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="loginbox"> 
    <img src="login.png" class="avatar"><br><br><br>
    ****<h1>Login Here</h1><br>****
```

Notice each `<li><a ...>` element has a matching set of closing tags - `</a></li>`. This prevents them from spilling out onto other tags, like your `<h1>`

Comment: Thank u very much sir, i was unable to find this out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<a>` tags are opening but not closing, that's what is causing unexpected behaviour. And you should try to better format your code, so that you can find this kind of errors more easilly. this should get what you want:

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="homeblack" href="https://www.facebook.com/abhishek.ruined">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a class="homeblack" href="/#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a class="homeblack" href="/#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="loginbox"> 
   <img src="login.png" class="avatar"><br><br><br>
   <h1>Login Here</h1>
   <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u very much sir, i was unable to find this out. Thanks a lot.